Autopath/Path typings for lodash.get() with an additional constrain
My use case is the following: I have a table where the columns and their values are dictated by an headers object like the following:
const headers = [
  {
    key: 'data-table-select',
    unhidable: true
  },
  {
    title: t('name'),
    align: 'start',
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    key: 'name'
  },
  {
    title: t('formulator-code'),
    align: 'start',
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    key: 'formulatorUser.code',
    apiKey: 'code'
  },
  {
    title: t('zdhc_subcategory'),
    align: 'start',
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    key: 'zdhc[0].subcategory',
    apiKey: 'subcategory'
  },
] as const satisfies DataTableHeader[]

For each filterable column I want to generate a list of items from another object (data) to feed a select.
interface MyData {
  id: string
  name: string
  formulatorUser: {
    id: string
    name: string
  }
  zdhc: Array<{
    id: string
    subcategory: string
  }>
}

const data: MyData[] = [...]

For the simplest case like the name column the items getter could be as straightforward as the following:
(header) => [...new Set(data.map(el => el[header.key as ApiKey<typeof headers>]))]

type ApiKey<T extends Array<{ key: string; filterable?: boolean }>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { filterable: true }
    ? T[K] extends { key: string }
      ? T[K]['key']
      : never
    : never
}[number]

These typings help me to ensure that the getter will always return string | number for every filterable column.
The problems start to to arise when I have more complex keys like formulatorUser.code or especially zdhc[0].subcategory, where the getter needs to be something like this:
import { get } from 'lodash-es'

(header) => [...new Set(data.map(el => get(el, header.key)))]

At this point I basically need to create typings for lodash.get with the additional constrain of being a filterable column. I wanted to borrow Autopath/Path from ts-toolbelt but they look to be broken (and even more broken with recent versions of Typescript up to the point of being unusable).
Could you please suggest a working implementation of Path/Autopath that works with arrays and nested objects and help to implement the additional filterable constrain?
